# ejabberd 20.04 mod_http_upload not working

Tags: ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd 20.04 on rhel 7.5. For testing purposes firewall is stopped, selinux disabled. I am using gajim 1.2.1 as a client. In my `/opt/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml` I have added only following lines:

```
listen:
  request_handlers:
    "/upload": mod_http_upload

shaper_rules:
  soft_upload_quota:
    1000: all
  hard_upload_quota:
    1100: all

modules:
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: "https://@HOST@:5443/upload"
    docroot: /ejabberd/upload/
```

everything else is by default. I haven't replaced the cert files. When I try to send file nothing happens. In `/opt/ejabberd/logs/ejabberd.log` there is only:

```
[info] <0.468.0>@mod_http_upload:create_slot:832 
   Got HTTP upload slot for test@chat.im.test/chat.im.test
   (file: testfile.txt, size: 14242)
[info] <0.393.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:256 
   (<0.551.0>) Accepted connection 
   [::ffff:192.168.10.10]:50749 -> [::ffff:192.168.20.10]:5443
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, if you provide an URL with HTTPS like

```
modules:
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
```

Then you must have TLS enabled like

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /upload: mod_http_upload
```

On the other hand, if you don't get enough information logged, you can try this, it may provide some meaningful key:

```
loglevel: debug
```

Answer (score 0):

That means it work perfect, nothing wrong ,check your /ejabberd/upload/ directory you will find your uploaded files in the sub folder created default by ejabberd

eg. /ejabberd/upload/--subfolder--/-subfolder/your-file